# SQLite transaction roll back default

Tags: sqlite

In the portion of code below, if the insert statement is purposely coded to fail, the three tables are still created but are empty.  Since they are in the same transaction as the insert statement, should they not roll back automatically by default and be dropped/not created?

Thank you.

```
void build_schema( char *j )
  {
    int rc;
    sqlite3_stmt *stmt;
    const char *tail;
    char sql[ 425 ] = "BEGIN EXCLUSIVE;"
                      "create table_1...;"
                      "create table_2 ...;"
                      "create table_3...;"
                      "insert into table_1 ...;"; 

    const char *ptr = &sql[0];
    while ( sqlite3_complete( ptr ) )
      {
        rc = sqlite3_prepare_v2( db, ptr, -1, &stmt, &tail );
        sqlite3_step( stmt );
        sqlite3_finalize( stmt );
        ptr = tail;
      }
```

---

This isn't a real answer but an explanation is provided [here](http://sqlite.1065341.n5.nabble.com/commit-and-rollback-td29773.html) at a sqlite forum. I was thinking too much like indexedDB in which some of this is automatic.  Following that information, the following set up worked for me but I'm sure it can be greatly improved.

```
while ( sqlite3_complete( ptr ) )
  {
    if ( ( rc = sqlite3_prepare_v2( db, ptr, -1, &stmt, &tail ) ) != SQLITE_OK ||
         ( rc = sqlite3_step( stmt ) ) != SQLITE_DONE ) 
      {
        sqlite3_finalize( stmt );
        err = rc;
        break;
      };
    sqlite3_finalize( stmt );
    ptr = tail;
  }

if ( err )
  {
    rc = sqlite3_exec( db, "ROLLBACK", NULL, NULL, NULL );
    if ( rc != SQLITE_OK ) 
      // Error message that failed to rollback.
      ;
    else
      // Error message that successfully rolled back.
      ;
  }
else
  {
    rc = sqlite3_exec( db, "COMMIT", NULL, NULL, NULL );
    if ( rc != SQLITE_OK ) 
      // Error message that failed to COMMIT.
      ;
    else
      // Message that creation of schema was successful.
      ;
  }
```

Comment: Where are you rolling back the transaction?

Comment: I'm not. Perhaps I've misunderstood what I read. I thought all SQL statements between the BEGIN and COMMIT were by default all rolled back if any one them did not complete successfully.  I placed an error in the insert statement expecting all statements in the transaction to be rolled back without catching the error and using ROLLBACK in the code itself.  Do BEGIN and COMMIT simply mark the boundaries for a ROLLBACK statement and without using ROLLBACK each statement in the transaction is still treated as its own transaction to succeed or fail indiviudally? Thanks.